_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_block.LZ4BlockError'>: import of module '_block' failed
I created a torch IterableDataset and rewrote the __iter__ function with:
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            obs, action, reward, discount, next_obs = self._sample()

            obs = decompress_img(obs, self._img_shape)
            next_obs = decompress_img(next_obs, self._img_shape)

            yield obs, action, reward, discount, next_obs

The obs and next_obs returned by _sample() are compressed with lz4.block.compress for memory optimization. Then, I want to decompress obs and next_obs before passed to the model. The decompress_img function has been stated globally.
However, I met the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xzc/miniforge3/envs/sb-zoo/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/xzc/miniforge3/envs/sb-zoo/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_block.LZ4BlockError'>: import of module '_block' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xzc/miniforge3/envs/sb-zoo/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/xzc/miniforge3/envs/sb-zoo/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)

